# Do you have to be in the United States to file a DMCA complaint?

Tags: copyright, dmca

I understand that DMCA complaints only work for search engines and webhosts which are based in the US.

However, does the person filing the complaint also have to be in the US, or can anyone in any country file a complaint to a US host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DMCA is U.S. law, however, many organizations and search engines participate in a sort of co-operative organization to satisfy these requests. If you file the DMCA complaint through Google, they inform Chilling Effects which is the de-facto organization which in turn will act as the information clearing house for anyone else who participates in removing copyrighted material. Your site does not have to be a U.S. site for this.

It certainly does not hurt to make this your first step. It may take a few days for everyone who is cooperating to see your complaint and act upon it. From there, you may have to take other steps for specific sites on a case by case basis. Just filing the complaint may be enough.

Comment: Thanks man... Filing DMCA's is my new pastime nowadays.. ;)

Comment: @CaptainCodeman It can be. However, overall, it is not as bad as it was 8-10 years ago with so many spamdexers trying to get rich off of all our backs with Adsense. Back then, it was driving well funded and mature sites into extinction by the droves. I actually gutted my sites and gave up for a long while.